# Создание и запись в файл на ассемблере. linux x64

Tags: linux, ассемблер, x86-64, syscall

Как в языке ассемблера x64 написать программу для создания файла и записи в него имени этого файла?(под linux). Написал вот такой код:

```
.data
msg:
  .string "textFile.txt"
  .set len, .-msg
.text

.globl _start
_start:
  #opening file
  mov $2, %rax # sys_open
  mov $msg, %rdi #filename
  mov $0x200, %rsi # flag - O_CREATE
  mov $200, %rdx # mode - S_IWUSR
  syscall
  # writing to file
  mov %rax, %rdi # putting descriptor to rdi
  mov $1, %rax # sys_write
  mov $msg, %rsi
  mov $len, %rdx
  syscall
  # closing file
  mov $3, %rax # sys_close
  syscall
  # exit
  mov $60,   %rax
  mov $0,    %rdi
  syscall
```

Но ничего не происходит, файл textFile.txt не создается. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: А почему sys_open у вас 2 ? В интернете пишут, что sys_open имеет код 5. а sys_write 4, sys_close 6

Comment: @Mike Эти коды разве не в 32 битном linux-е?
 Я смотрел по вот этой таблице для 64 битного http://blog.rchapman.org/posts/Linux_System_Call_Table_for_x86_64/

Comment: Хм. порылся в /usr/include/asm в unistd_64.h действительно 2, а в unistd_32.h  5. Ну и бардак у них с номерами... Зато O_CREAT описан в /usr/include/asm-generic/fcntl.h как 0x100 ... Посмотрите у себя в системе объявления всего этого